# Unable to handle iframe in selenium with tinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, iframe, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to access to iFrame

```
    <iframe id="frame1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;" tabindex="100">
    <html>
    <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body id="tiny1" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.get('frame1').onLoad.dispatch();">
    <p/>
    </body>
    </html>
   </iframe>
```

And I want to sendKeys() to the body with id=tinymce. But when I tried to switchTo().frame , it does not work.

My Java code:

```
public void enterArea(String object, String content){
        String driverWindows = driver.toString();
        driver.switchTo().frame(selenium.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frame1']")));         
        String driverIFrame = driver.toString();
        WebElement contentTextArea = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 3))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='tiny1']/p")));
        contentTextArea.sendKeys(content);
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
```

The 2 `driverWindows` and `driverIFrame` always return the same string, it means the `web driver` has not switched, right?

Could you help me access to  elements? 
Please do let me know if require any further details.
Thank you.

Comment: Here body and frame are separate so why you are switching to frame if you want to send text to body?

Comment: @HelpingHands: sorry, my typo. I've edited.

Comment: Did you try by ID to identify iframe?

Comment: @HelpingHands: Yes, i tried, driver.switchTo().frame("frame1");, but it's still the same.

Comment: It should work...Did you debug code?

Comment: Hi @scorpion Is it tinymce editor??Do you have multiple tinymce editors in the page??

Comment: @HelpingHands: I've already debug, nothing error. But cannot sendkeys as I expected.

Comment: @Vicky: yes, you're right, this's tinymce editor? And I just have 1 tinyEditor in iframe1. TinyEditor has another behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='frame1']")));

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("testing");

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**Another option using javascript**

Do not switch into the iframe if you are using javascript

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('testing');");
```

I tested the above code with timymce editors it was working fine

**EDIT** :

```
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='frame1']")));

 //Do not use path body/p you need to send text to body tag

 (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//body[@id='tiny1']")));

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@id='tiny1']")).sendKeys("testing");

 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope this helps you..Kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: Very, very helpful to me. It worked fine.Thank you so much.
But could you tell me why my code did not work? 
Why we have to use implicitlyWait instead of ExpectedConditions. ? 
And why we should use tagName body ? 
Just want to understand more to have knowledge.
Thank again.

Comment: Happy to be of help :)